# Crash bluetooth boot

Tags: boot, 23.04

I am using Ubuntu 23.04. When booting my laptop gets stuck at the following black screen:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)